# How can I get parameter estimates such as the mean of the parameter estimates of k subgroups of a dataset over 100 trials in R?

Tags: r, simulation, lm

I'm using R. I have the following problem: I need to perform over 100 trials the linear model for each subgroup k (with equal size) of my dataset and then I want to get the estimates of the parameters as the mean of the parameters of each subgroup over 100 trials.
I've developed the following code. I'm not sure I know how to store, in the two loop, the estimates of the parameters at each iteration that I will need to compute the mean. I used a list ("res"), but since at each repetition I have to store a vector maybe it is not a good choice:

```
# Define var-cov matrix
rho <- 0.5
row1 <- rho^(c(0:18))
row2 <- rho^(c(1,0:17))
row3 <- rho^(c(2:1,0:16))
row4 <- rho^(c(3:1,0:15))
row5 <- rho^(c(4:1,0:14))
row6 <- rho^(c(5:1,0:13))
row7 <- rho^(c(6:1,0:12)) 
row8 <- rho^(c(7:1,0:11))
row9 <- rho^(c(8:1,0:10))
row10 <- rho^(c(9:1,0:9))
row11 <- rho^(c(10:1,0:8))
row12 <- rho^(c(11:1,0:7))
row13 <- rho^(c(12:1,0:6))
row14 <- rho^(c(13:1,0:5))
row15 <- rho^(c(14:1,0:4))
row16 <- rho^(c(15:1,0:3))
row17 <- rho^(c(16:1,0:2))
row18 <- rho^(c(17:1,0:1))
row19 <- rho^(c(18:1,0))
S = round(rbind(row1,row2,row3,row4,row5,row6,row7,row8,row9,row10,row11,row12,row13,row14,row15,row16,row17,row18,row19),4)

library(tidyr)
colnames(S) = c("X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","X10","X11","X12","X13","X14","X15","X16","X17","X18","X19","X20")
rownames(S) = colnames(S)

# Make mean vector
mus = rep(1,19); names(mus) = colnames(S)

 res <- list()
 result <- list()
 for(ii in 1:100){ 
    df = mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mus, Sigma = S)
    beta <- c(1, runif(19, min = -2.5, max = 2.5))
    eps <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
    sigma <- 0.2*(norm(df*beta, type = '2')/norm(eps, type = '2'))
    y <- rowSums(df*beta + sigma*eps)
    df <- data.frame(cbind(y, df))
    ind = sample(rep(1:10,each = nrow(df)/10)) # split the dataset in k=10 subgroups
    k <-lapply(split(1:nrow(df),ind), function(i) df[i,])
    for(i in 1:10){
        fit <-lm(formula = y ~ X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11+X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+X20, 
            data= k[[i]])
        res[[i]] <- fit$coefficients
                  }
        result[[ii]] <- mean(res[[i]])
      }
```

Could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  "There's something wrong" isn't very helpful.  Can you be more specific?  Do you get an error message?  if so, where?  What does it say?  Do you not get the output you expect?  if so, what do you get and what do you want?  Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question so that it is a minimal working example.

Comment: yes, you're right! Something wrong means: "Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : objet "X2" not found". It seems to me that in the second loop R is not able to read the subgroups

Comment: `k` and `result` are both lists, so you should use `[[` to access individual elements rather than `[`.  That will get you started: you code runs, but does not produce any results.  Please read the post I linked to in my other comment and then modify your question so that it is an MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps to think about what is the structure you need. From what I can see, the result list can be calculated after you consolidated your coefficents. If you prefer to have it in a data.frame, and keep track of the simulation no, split no, then try this below:

```
library(purrr)
library(MASS)
library(dplyr)
library(broom)

regform =as.formula('y ~ X2+X3+X4+X5+X6+X7+X8+X9+X10+X11+X12+X13+X14+X15+X16+X17+X18+X19+X20')

func = function(ii,mus,S,matrix=FALSE){

 df = mvrnorm(n = 1000, mu = mus, Sigma = S)
 beta <- c(1, runif(19, min = -2.5, max = 2.5))
 eps <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
 sigma <- 0.2*(norm(df*beta, type = '2')/norm(eps, type = '2'))
 y <- rowSums(df*beta + sigma*eps)
 df <- data.frame(cbind(y, df))
 df$ind = sample(rep(1:10,each = nrow(df)/10)) 
 
 df <- df %>% group_by(ind) %>% do(tidy(lm(regform,data=.))) %>% mutate(sim=ii)
 if(matrix){
     return(split(df$estimate,df$ind))
 }else{
     return(df)
   }  
} 
        
result = 1:100 %>% map_dfr(~func(.x,mus=mus,S=S,matrix=FALSE))

> head(result)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   ind [1]
    ind term        estimate std.error statistic p.value   sim
  <int> <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
1     1 (Intercept)    13.7      13.3      1.02   0.309      1
2     1 X2            -11.1       5.51    -2.02   0.0467     1
3     1 X3              5.61      5.86     0.957  0.341      1
4     1 X4             -1.48      6.22    -0.239  0.812      1
5     1 X5             -3.82      5.89    -0.649  0.518      1
6     1 X6              2.88      5.95     0.485  0.629      1
> tail(result)
# A tibble: 6 x 7
# Groups:   ind [1]
    ind term  estimate std.error statistic p.value   sim
  <int> <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
1    10 X15      11.9       6.41     1.85   0.0679   100
2    10 X16      -8.86      5.77    -1.54   0.128    100
3    10 X17       6.68      5.70     1.17   0.245    100
4    10 X18       3.73      5.81     0.641  0.523    100
5    10 X19      -5.28      5.55    -0.952  0.344    100
6    10 X20       1.14      5.40     0.211  0.833    100
```

As mentioned, the mean of the coefficients you need is simply grouping by sim and ind:

```
result %>% group_by(sim,ind) %>% summarize(estimate=mean(estimate))
# A tibble: 1,000 x 3
# Groups:   sim [100]
     sim   ind estimate
   <int> <int>    <dbl>
 1     1     1    0.800
 2     1     2    0.771
 3     1     3    0.807
 4     1     4    0.277
 5     1     5    0.632
 6     1     6    0.788
 7     1     7    0.878
 8     1     8    0.987
 9     1     9    0.764
10     1    10    0.611
# … with 990 more rows
```

The above is I think cleaner and easier for keeping tracking.. downside is that it uses a data.frame and might be costly if you are doing tons of regressions.

The other possibility is to store everything in a matrix:

```
result = map(1:100,~func(.x,mus=mus,S=S,matrix=TRUE))
```

And to get the means:

```
map(result,~map(.x,mean))
```

Comment: Your solution is really helpful! Thank you very much  for your help!

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, I was wondering if it is possible to run the regressions in parallel and not sequentially, in this case the running time will decrease considerably. Could you say something on this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes u can. Look into something like https://github.com/DavisVaughan/furrr

Comment: I'm trying to apply the future_map() function to your code. I'm using it outside of the loop, result = 1:100 %>% future_map(map_dfr(~func(.x,mus=mus,S=S,matrix=FALSE)))...but doesn't work. Can you give me some hints?

Comment: ```1:100 %>%  future_map_dfr(~func(.x,mus=mus,S=S,matrix=FALSE))```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot..I thought of extending what you have done for linear regression to the quantile regression for a specific percentile (say, 0.99). In this case I've considered the following part in loop:  df <- df %>% group_by(block) %>% do(tidy(rq(regform,data=., tau=0.99))) %>% mutate(sim=ii). But when I run (result = 1:10 %>% future_map_dfr(~func(.x,mus=mus,S=S,matrix=FALSE))), I get this error: "Error in UseMethod("tidy") : no applicable method for 'tidy' applied to an object of class "rq". What should I use?